# Export business data from UI5 to Excel

Tags: odata, sapui5, export-to-excel

I have a table with product details like *ID*, *description*, *price* etc.. I am trying to export these data to an Excel.

### Issue

If I just do `getModel("A")`, and then bind few properties of "A", which are **not** nested, the excel is downloaded fine. But if there is any other structure, which I am trying to access for example, `getModel("A").getProperty("/Person/PersonFullName")`, it will leave that **column blank**.

```js
{ // Controller
  onExport: function() {
    var aCols, aProducts, oSettings;
    aCols = this.createColumnConfig();
    aProducts = this.getView().getModel("A"); // A has nested/deep entities
    oSettings = {
      workbook: { columns: aCols },
      dataSource: aProducts
    };
    var oSpreadsheet = new Spreadsheet(oSettings); // required "sap/ui/export/Spreadsheet"
    oSpreadsheet.build();
  },            

  createColumnConfig: function() {
    return [
      {
        label: 'Product ID',
        property: 'name'
      },
      {
        label: 'Category',
        property: 'BillTo/BillToName', //Not able to get this property
      }
    ];
  },

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [API reference of `sap/ui/export/Spreadsheet`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.export.Spreadsheet), the `dataSource` setting object awaits one of the following arguments:

> - *Map of data source properties*, // See API reference for available options
> - *URL to an OData service*
> - *JSON array*

But in your code, the `aProduct`, which is assigned to the `dataSource`, is a reference to the `"A"` model which is **invalid**.

The `dataSource` should be set, depending on the model type, accordingly:

### With `ODataModel`

```js
const odataListBinding = this.byId("myResponsiveTable").getBinding("items");
const serviceEntryPath = "/sap.app/dataSources/<sourceName>/uri"; // See manifest.json for <sourceName>
const serviceUrl = this.getOwnerComponent().getManifestEntry(serviceEntryPath);
```

```js
{ // Constructor settings of sap/ui/export/Spreadsheet
  dataSource: {
    type: "OData",
    useBatch: true,
    serviceUrl: serviceUrl,
    headers: odataListBinding.getModel().getHeaders(),
    dataUrl: odataListBinding.getDownloadUrl(), // serviceUrl + "/Orders" + added queries ($expand, $select, ...)
    count: odataListBinding.getLength(),
    sizeLimit: /*e.g.*/1000,
  },
  worker: true, // false if working with mock server or if CSP is enabled.
  fileName: "myExportedDataFromODataV2.xlsx"
}
```

**Note:** Please make sure that the corresponding `$expand` parameter is included in the `dataUrl`. Otherwise, nested properties won't be exported.

#### Samples

- My sample with [nested properties ($expand)](https://embed.plnkr.co/THW41Upr5Uhk0Y2g?show=controller/App.controller.js,preview)
- Sample from the [Demo Kit](https://ui5.sap.com/#/sample/sap.ui.export.sample.table/code/Spreadsheet.controller.js)

### With client-side models (e.g. `JSONModel`)

```js
{ // Constructor settings of sap/ui/export/Spreadsheet
  dataSource: myJSONModel.getProperty("/SomeCollection"), // returns an array
  fileName: "myExportedDataFromPlainJSON.xlsx"
}
```

#### Samples

- My sample with [nested properties](https://embed.plnkr.co/vVhRhvjQUkWM6Lri?show=controller/App.controller.js,preview)
- Sample from the [Demo Kit](https://ui5.sap.com/#/sample/sap.ui.export.sample.json/code/Spreadsheet.controller.js)

Comment: Is it possible to set up count attribute when using client side model. Eg
`code`
        fExp: function(**actualData**){           
                         var config = {
    workbook: {
     columns: this.createColumn()
    },    
    dataSource: **actualData**, // **how to set count**
    fileName: "A",
    count: 10   // **does not work as count is a nested property within 
                                                           datasource**
   };
`code`
On export get a warning dialog from SAP: Export Document does not have count & user must decide whether to proceed or not

Comment: @THI Sorry, can't answer right away. I think it's better to open a new question.