# What's wrong with using JSONModel for data from OData services in UI5?

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I had to develop (with a teammate) an application which contains mainly a table with a dozen of filters, and rows loaded from an OData service with roughly 400k entries. Since we had to frequently upload the model without storing changes into the server, and we wanted a user to immediately see the results of the changes he makes, we decided to build `sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel` at the start of the application, which loads its data from `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel`.

We found out that, in this way, the application was **significantly** faster than going with the direct OData binding approach, and our trick made the app work perfectly.

So, our question is: are there any drawbacks in doing what we did? Bear in mind that we both don't have much experience with the SAP Fiori world, and that in our application users **don't** have to write data nor create new entries in the table, they will only view data, use some filters, sortings, and download the CSV once they filtered the table.

EDIT: [Here](https://github.com/mdonaEstilos/mcve_table)'s the link for the repo containing only an mcve, where I used Northwind OData, and do problematic operations directly on the ODataModel, without using an intermediate JSONModel. The crucial operation is a filter that displays only selected item of the table: you can change Northwind OData to any service you want and see that if the number of rows of the table grows substantially, this operation requires a lot of time.
Sap UI5 version used: 1.84.0

Comment: If your app is much faster that way have you thought about improving the backend? Like properly implementing paging (skip and top parameter)?

Comment: @Marc I think what Donax wants to achieve is the immediate response after filtering, sorting, etc. which is possible only if the entire data are available on the client-side. I.e. no round-trips at all. But still, there is no need for a `JSONModel` in that case as explained in the answer below. The only thing I question is whether users are really willing to download 400k entries everytime the app opens.

Comment: Yeah Boghyon is right, and I can't touch anything from backend. Agree that users shouldn't need to download the entire dataset every time, we also implemented some sort of prior filtering in order to at least filter out the majority of useless entries

Comment: edit: changed repo link. There was an undesired issue in the former, so please delete everything if saved something and refer only to the new repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I'd reconsider loading 400.000 entries at once. This roughly corresponds to **10+ MB** of data load when the app launches.
2. About the "trick"..:

   > our trick made the app work perfectly.

   The main difference between server-side models (like `ODataModel`) and client-side ones (like `JSONModel`) is that **server-side models are aware of the query specification** implemented by the backend service and thus can let the client (UI5) **optimize the runtime behavior**, while **writing less code** (often declaratively), and **on top of the client-side features**. In our case, `ODataModel` also supports client operation mode:

   ```json
   "models" : {
     "": {
       "dataSource": "myODataService",
       "settings": {
         "defaultOperationMode": "Client"
   ```

   This will also load all entries at once for the table without having to use an intermediate `JSONModel`. Sorting, filtering, etc. will all happen on the client side. **But again:** the operation mode should be selected depending on the amount of data, target users, devices, and use cases.

Since `ODataModel` even supports [exporting data to another format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54134943/5846045), I see such intermediate `JSONModel` as a pure overhead when dealing with data from an OData service.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! We already knew that we could load odata service in Client mode, and filters worked on client side as expected, but for some reason when we make changes on the server side model it's **much** slower than doing so with the json model, even if the only change we made was a property setting

Comment: @Donax UI5 does have an [issue with performance in change detection](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2600) on bindings. But that slowness applies also to the `JSONModel` **unless** you let the framework update the bound value via TwoWay binding. In that case, the change detection is performed _asynchronously_ (doesn't block the main-/UI-thread of the browser). With `model.setProperty`, an extra `true` flag needs to be passed as a 4th argument in order to perform the change detection asynchronously. How did you do it with ODataModel? Via TwoWay binding? Or with `model.setProperty`?

Comment: @Donax There could be also issues with limited memory on the device. I could imagine OData bindings allocating more memory than plain client-side bindings from JSONModel. This needs some serious testing.

Comment: I used model.setProperty in both cases. I don't notice that slowness in JSONModel, to give you an idea, using a table with roughly 1k rows the change (and filtering on the changed field) takes less than a second with the JSONModel, and more than 2 minutes with the ODataModel

Comment: @Donax Could you update the question with an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your app? And a *small* set of sample data. I'd like to reproduce the same issue on my side so that I can take a deeper look. Also, what are the target device, OS, and the UI5 version?

Comment: We're using google chrome on a windows 10 desktop, UI5 version 1.84.0.

I'll prepare an mcve and add it to the question as soon as it's ready

Comment: @Donax I just noticed you updated the question with a link to the repo. Will take a look when I get a chance.. if this question is still relevant to you after 2 years :)

Comment: thank you! Not really for me, but might be useful for others

Comment: @Donax I just took a look. The implementation of displaying and managing the selected rows could be improved by leveraging the table's selection plugin (e.g. the `sap.ui.table.plugins.MultiSelectionPlugin`) instead of iterating over the entire list of rows binding instances synchronously at once every time the user clicks on the `"toggleShowSelected"` button. It is true that `v2.ODataModel#setProperty` has more tasks compared to `JSONModel#setProperty` but if the application takes minutes handling an event, it's a strong indication that the current implementation design needs be reconsidered.