# How to export data from UI5 to Excel with custom file name

Tags: sapui5, export-to-excel

I'd like to download the table as an **Excel file**. But when the function is triggered, it always downloads as "data.csv" by default. I want a different name for the file. So how can I change the name of the downloaded file into something else?

```js
{ // Snippet from my controller
  toExcel: function () {
    var oExport = new Export({
      exportType: new ExportTypeCSV({ // required from "sap/ui/core/util/ExportTypeCSV"
        separatorChar: ",",
        charset: "utf-8"
      }),
      models: this.getView().getModel("oListOrderMod_rent"),
      rows: { path: "/" },
      columns: [
        {
          name: "Tenant Name",
          template: {
            content: "{tentName}"
          }
        },
        {
          name: "Address",
          template: {
            content: "{h_address}"
          }
        },
        // ...
      ]
    });
    oExport.saveFile().catch(function(oError) {
      MessageBox.error("Error when downloading data. ..." + oError);
    }).then(function() {
      oExport.destroy();
    });
  },
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Clicking that button downloads the file. I want it to say something other than "data.csv"

Comment: If you're developing with SAPUI5, consider using the [module `sap/ui/export/Spreadsheet`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.export.Spreadsheet) instead, in which you can also configure the exported file name. The module **`sap/ui/core/util/Export` is deprecated!**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export values of OData with nested properties to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54083928/export-values-of-odata-with-nested-properties-to-excel)

Comment: Does it **have to be** in the `*.csv` format? Or is it fine to export the file in `*.xlsx`? The question is a bit unclear since the title as well as the screenshot suggests that the data should be exported as an Excel format (`*.xlsx`).

Comment: Yes, your link works

Comment: Since `sap/ui/core/util/Export` is deprecated, and since the latest best-practice for the same request is provided in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54083928/export-values-of-odata-with-nested-properties-to-excel), please mark this question as a duplicate for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is quite obvious if you take a look into the [API description](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.util.Export#methods/saveFile):

The method `saveFile` has a parameter which is the filename.

So just pass that parameter.

```js
oExport.saveFile("myNewFileName.csv")
    .catch(function (oError) {
        // ...
    })
    .then(function () {
        // ...
    });
```